# Using IsNull in flows on a formula text field

Tags: process, isblank

I read on this forum that we should use IsBlank for text fields, which I assume holds true to formula text fields. I'm not sure however that holds true for flows as I don't see the option for IsBlank.

I have a flow that should exit the flow if this formula text field (It takes a URL and pulls out certain characters from the URL, think of it like pulling the 18 character SFDC ID out of a URL so you only have the 18 digit ID left) is null. I did that with a decision element that says: ID_Field__c IsNull $globalconstant.True which should exit the flow, but I instead get the unhandled fault error.

[image: Decision Element]

I'll post the error in case that helps. There are actually two errors, but my rep isn't at 10 yet so I just posted 1. As you can tell I'm pretty lost, but feel I may be close to getting this to work.

[image: Error #1]

Comment: How are you getting the value for varPartnerId? Looks like you are passing in the records id, presume from process builder? You also need to pass the variable, unless you have a lookup in your flow that is setting the value to a flow variable or into an sobject variable

Comment: Looks like the error is obscured in the email. Use the ... to expand the rest of the message.